# For @sqslistener, value pass from environment variable other than .yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, amazon-sqs, sqslistener

I am currently using Amazon SQS to consume message in springboot.
e.g.

```
@sqslistener(value ="amazon.sqs.queue-name")
public void sesListener() {
// some statement
}
```

application.yaml

[image]

Note : **amazon.sqs.queue-name** is read from application.yaml which is working fine.
But Now I want to read sqs-name from environment variable, so I no need to put this queue name in application.yaml file.
Can anyone please help me out for this use-case ?

FYI : I want to use something like env.getProperty("queue-name") to read queue-name from environment variable. Currently I tried below workaround

`@SqsListener(value = "#{ environment['queue-name'] }"`

And also want to debug, that SqsListener is listening to the correct queue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@sqslistener(value ="${amazon.sqs.queue-name}")
public void sesListener() {
// some statement
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?